# How To Separate Excel Data With Multiple Numbers In One Cell

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I copied some data from a website and the data looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to either separate the data or sum the three numbers in each cell?

Answer (score 0):

So, I would use the spaces to separate like so:

```
=trim(left(A1,find(" ",A1,1)-1))
```

and:

```
=trim(mid(A1,find(" ",A1,1)+1,find(" ",A1,find(" ",A1,1)+1)-1))
```

and:

```
=trim(right(A1,len(A1)-find(" ",A1,find(" ",A1,1)+1))
```

wrote these by hand so not tested but you should be able to get each to work then sum them.