# I have value "12345 (POS) / 45678 (APOS)" or "12345 (POS) / 45678 (APOS)" in excel cell and i want to extract in this format "12345,45678"

Tags: excel, exception, excel-formula, excel-2010

Work done: =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2," (POS) / ",",")," (APOS)","") but work for one condition.

but i want to add both condition: "12345 (POS) / 45678 (APOS) " or "12345 (POS) - 45678 (APOS) "

Comment: What is input? What is output?

Comment: You could use `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2, "-","/")," (POS) / ",",")," (APOS)","")`

Comment: Try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70791647/4961700

Answer (score 0):

This will get you there, but there is an open IF you can clean up.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("/",A1)),SUBSTITUTE(A1," (POS) / ",","),IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-",A1)),SUBSTITUTE(A1," (POS) - ",",")))," (APOS)","")
```

[image: Solution]